# ¿En qué situaciones puedo usar el patrón p ~ ul como selector de CSS?

Tags: css, selectores-css

Quisiera saber en qué momento puedo usar este patrón de selector de elementos en CSS.

W3Schools nos dice que 

Selects every  element that is preceded by a

element

Pero exactamente qué significa esto? Precedido como hermano o como padre?
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

### Explicación

El combinador `~` separa dos selectores y selecciona el segundo elemento sólo si está precedido por el primero y ambos comparten un padre común. Es decir, si tu tienes en base a tu ejemplo `p ~ ul`, los estilos serian aplicados al `ul` que este después de una etiqueta `p`, pero solo si tienen el mismo padre ambos elementos.

### Ejemplo

```css
p ~ span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Este span no es rojo.</span>
  <p>Aquí hay un párrafo.</p>
  <code>Aquí hay algo de código.</code>
  <span>Aquí hay un span. Es rojo porque va precedido de un párrafo y ambos comparten el mismo padre.</span>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Otro parrafo</p>
</div>
<span>Este span no es rojo</span>
```

Comment: Bryant gracias por comentar.

Pero no terminé por entender, te refieres al <p>Otro parrafo</p> o al <p>Aquí hay un párrafo.</p>

Porque con <p>Aquí hay un párrafo.</p>, esta p está precedida por span

pero con <p>Otro parrafo</p> entonces sí span está precedido por p, siguiendo la cascada.

?

Comment: El ejemplo muestra que los span que tenga antes una p, tendran texto rojo, pero deben estar en el mismo contenedor, en este caso el div, el primer span esta antes de la p "Aqui hay un parrafo" por lo que no cambia de color, pero el siguiente span si que cambia porque tiene antes a la etiqueta p mencionada.

Comment: Y el span que esta al final no es rojo a pesar de que tiene una p antes, porque la p esta adentro de un contenedor, el div, y el span esta fuera, por lo que el estilo no le aplica a ese span

Comment: Bryant, entonces p ~ span no es más que una expansión de "p + span", pero "p+span" elegiría al hermano directo mientras que "p~span" elegiría al hermano directo ó **lejano**,  Ambos con el mismo padre. estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Exactamente, esa seria una forma de verlo

Comment: Gracias Bryant, feliz navidad

Comment: De nada, feliz navidad